# Batch remove reminders (alerts) from Outlook 2013 email messages

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, microsoft-outlook-2007

I have thousands of messages in the inbox for which reminders are set (or maybe it is called Alert in English version).

Is there a way to remove reminders (alerts) from a group of selected (but not all) messages, without discarding the flags?

Here is what I have: flag with reminder set

[image]

and this is how I want it: reminder disabled, but flag still set:

[image]

but doing it for all selected messages.

Research I did: There is no Quick Step to remove the reminder, and flag dialog cannot be shown for a group of selected messages. Flags can be cleared for selected messages with a Quick Step, but I do not want to clear the flags completely, only to disable the reminder. I could probably write an AHK script, but I feel it is too fragile and might mess things up if something goes out of sync.

Comment: This may not be the final answer, but is it sort of what you are looking for? http://www.slipstick.com/tutorial/change-the-reminder-on-several-appointments-at-once/

Comment: @MusselmanLLC I have seen their tutorial before asking. No, this does not work on email messages: when I try to drag them, the cursor turns into "prohibited action" sign and nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

There is a free [Delete Fields](https://www.outlookfreeware.com/en/products/all/OutlookHeadersDelete) utility that does exactly what you want. Just install it **with Outlook Add-In support** and you can run it using right-click context menu on selected messages or for the selected Outlook folder(s) or event for the entire mailbox.

Specify the following fields names to delete:

```
ReminderSet,ReminderTime,ReminderSignalTime
```

This will delete reminders without clearing flag status.

DISCLAIMER: I recommend this tools because I'm one of the developers, so feel free to ask any further questions.